# Swift: Creating a csv file in Documents Directory

Tags: ios, swift, csv, nsfilemanager, nsfilehandle

I am creating a registration form application. The registration form data will be saved in a CSV file. I need to create a csv file in the documents directory and be able to write to it. I'm pretty new to Swift so I'm having a bit of trouble. This is what I've got so far.

```
var fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
var fileHandle: NSFileHandle

@IBAction func submitForm(sender: AnyObject) {
    mySingleton.filename = mySingleton.filename + ".csv"
    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
    let filePath = documentsPath + mySingleton.filename

    if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(mySingleton.filename) {
        fileManager.createFileAtPath(filePath, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
        fileHandle = ...
    }

}
```

Obviously the code I'm having trouble with is the FileHandle which is what allows to to modify the file. In objective-c it would look something like this:

```
fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:event];
```

Then obviously if I wanted to write to the file I could do something like this:

```
[fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
[fileHandle writeData:[formData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[fileHandle closeFile];
```

So I'm really only struggling with that one part. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem ? You want to translate this objective-C to Swift ?

Comment: Yes essentially. Not quite sure of how it is to be programmed in Swift.

Comment: What is the type of your "formData" object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift, `fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath` has become an initializer of `NSFileHandle`, adopting the Swift naming convention of avoiding repetition and taking the end of the Objective-C method name, making it the parameter name:

```
let fileHandle = NSFileHandle(forUpdatingAtPath: yourPath)
```

Comment: Ah Okay! So it's forUpdatingAtPath! Thank you so much. I have been looking for the forever aha

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add these two keys in info.plist and set them to "**YES**"

**Supports opening documents in place**

**Application supports iTunes file sharing**